# Clear data in memory for Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function which stores "Rules" in memory

These rules are loaded from the database and hardly ever change

Therefore, I plan to hold them in memory inside a single service that is setup by DI when my function starts

If the data is changed in the database, I need to detect this and reload the information

Am I right in thinking that I cant have 2 triggers for a function?

Do I need to be heading towards Redis and having something that clears the rules from Redis once changed in the database then that would force a database read?  Is there an easier way?

My function is probably going to be consumption based, and would be run on the standard tier, i.e. not premium

Paul

Comment: One of the "gotchas" with functions is that the backplane can scale at any time to new nodes, meaning that your cache is no longer accessible since function copy b is no longer sharing the same memory as function copy a.  Whenever sharing state across functions, you *must* provide a way to restore that state if it is unavailable.

Comment: I don’t need to share data as such I just need to be able to refresh the rules

Comment: If you wanted to store something in memory, you would need a durable pub/sub subscriber per instance running that could respond to rule change events.  Otherwise, you might want to look at delegating rules to redis and refreshing from redis every few minutes.